# Defining classes with and without (object)

Tags: python, class, python-3.x

I am trying to learn Python 3. In a book I read, to define a class you use:

```
class Classname:
    # and so on
```

In another it says:

```
class Classname(object):
    # and so on
```

Which is the right way to do it? How are they different?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there is a difference only for python 2.7: [old-style and new-style classes in Python 2.7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13816849/old-style-and-new-style-classes-in-python-2-7)

in python 3

```
class SomeClass:
    ...
```

is the same as

```
class SomeClass(object):
    ...
```

Answer (score 3):

In the specific case that you mention (i.e. inheriting from `object`) this makes no difference in Python 3. In Python 2 this was a distinction between old style classes

```
class Classname:
    ...
```

and new style classes

```
class Classname(object):
    ...
```

which behaved differently as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54867/what-is-the-difference-between-old-style-and-new-style-classes-in-python) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015417/python-class-inherits-object).

As you are programming in Python 3 I would just omit it to make your code easier to read. Since all objects implicitly inherit from `object` this information is not helpful to a reader of your code.